# Creating a Regex with specific condition

Tags: c#, regex

I want to create a regex for extracting blocks from a text file.
The block must be between to known value and contains a specific Word.

What I m using right now is this

```
  Regex.Matches (fileContent, $"START_BLOCK SOMEWORD[^#]+?END_BLOCK")
                    .OfType<Match> ().Select (m => m.Value).ToList ();
```

which only returns the matches that start with START_BLOCK and have only one space between the start and SOMEWORD.
I know that between the start and the word can be only spaces or control characters.

```
.....
PRG
PROGRAM PRG
VAR
END_VAR
0A
TRUE
ANDA
TRUE
OR
RESULTd
TEST_F
.....
```

From this, I want to extract the part beginning with `PROGRAM PRG` and ending with `RESULTd`. So the block between `PRG` and `TEST_F` and containing(directly after PRG but can contain more than spaces or carriage returns) the Keyword PROGRAM.

Note that the file can contain more than one PROGRAM but every one has a unique name.

Comment: Can you add some examples?

Comment: Please refer to the various components you're referring to in a *consistent way* so people can understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the lines that contains PROGRAM and then match until the first occurrence of RESULTd

```
.*\bPROGRAM\b.*(?:\r?\n(?!RESULTd\b).*)*\r?\nRESULTd\b
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=.*%5cbPROGRAM%5cb.*%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!RESULTd%5cb%29.*%29*%5cr%3f%5cnRESULTd%5cb&i=PRG%0d%0aPROGRAM+PRG%0d%0aVAR%0d%0aEND_VAR%0d%0a0A%0d%0aTRUE%0d%0aANDA%0d%0aTRUE%0d%0aOR%0d%0aRESULTd%0d%0aTEST_F)

If the words PRG and TESTF should be there and there can be one or more whitespace chars `\s*` after PRG, you can use a capturing group.

```
PRG\r?\n\s*(PROGRAM\b.*(?:\r?\n(?!RESULTd\b).*)*\r?\nRESULTd)\r?\nTEST_F
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=PRG%5cr%3f%5cn%5cs*%28PROGRAM%5cb.*%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!RESULTd%5cb%29.*%29*%5cr%3f%5cnRESULTd%29%5cr%3f%5cnTEST_F&i=PRG%0d%0aPROGRAM+PRG%0d%0aVAR%0d%0aEND_VAR%0d%0a0A%0d%0aTRUE%0d%0aANDA%0d%0aTRUE%0d%0aOR%0d%0aRESULTd%0d%0aTEST_F) | [C# demo](http://ideone.com/YT7nzg)

[image]

Your code might look like

```
string pattern = @"PRG\r?\n\s*(PROGRAM\b.*(?:\r?\n(?!RESULTd\b).*)*\r?\nRESULTd)\r?\nTEST_F";
var items = Regex.Matches(fileContent, pattern)
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select (m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```